# How to maintain a copy of a hash with original values after changing some of its values in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have tried to phrase this to the best of my ability. I have a hash that I perform some operations on but before I do this, I store this hash in another variable. Now when I access this variable, the values seem to have changed, how can I go around it. Example:

```
hash = {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
hash_copy = hash
hash["a"]=4
puts(hash_copy["a"]) #prints 4 instead of 1
```

How can I get the put statement to print 1 instead of 4, that is, print the original value.

Answer (score 2):

`deep_dup` is your friend
`hash_copy = hash` is just assigning a pointer not making a copy

so ruby specific options are `clone` and `deep_copy`
In your case `copy` will do but both should work fine for you

Ruby clone

```
hash_copy = hash.clone
```

Rails, a little buggy in earlier rails versions but is a ruby function and will work for you

```
hash_copy = hash.deep_dup
```

is what you need

https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup

Comment: is this a rails function? is there a plain ruby version that I can use?

Comment: @DivyanshMishra yes, it is a rails function as linked to in my answer as your question was tagged with rails, I'll update my answer with a ruby hash duplication answer

Comment: @DivyanshMishra, updated

Comment: thanks for your inputs. Using deep_copy (I have a nested hash), I get this error "undefined method `deep_copy' for Peml:Module (NoMethodError)". Peml is the name of the module I'm working in. Is this funtion associated with a gem?

Comment: @DivyanshMishra Sorry deep copy was a method I wrote for my own purposes years ago and forgot it was one of mine, deep_dup is a ruby function and works for your requirements

Comment: @DivyanshMishra Updated again, aplologies for my misleading answer with regards to deep_copy

Answer (score 1):

Use `Hash#merge` instead which returns a modified copy of the hash instead:

```
hash = {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
hash_copy = hash.merge(a: 4)
```

In general assigning hash keys should only be done to explicitly modify a hash - for everything else there are better methods.